# How to validate my knowledge of models implementation, pros and cons and area of applicability?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, education

So I've been doing ML for ~2 years in industry, I'm a BSc in applied math, finished several courses on ML/DL on coursera, read some specific topics in ML/DL books. Seem to be in the know, more or less.

But the catch is: I've never *really* validated my knowledge, as in taken an exam or certification. Some time has passed since I read theory and I sort of think that I'm losing it (especially since all I did was time-series forecasting).

What are the possible ways to validate that I actually understand stuff? Do I just text random ML experts "hey could I tell you stuff and you say whether that's bs or not"?..

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a definite answer for your question, but one way to validate your ML knowledge is to attempt certain problems that are asked in ML interviews for jobs. It might be a good starting point although it will not cover all the relevant concepts. Two such resources are

- The [questions](https://huyenchip.com/ml-interviews-book/contents/part-ii.-questions.html) section in Chip Huyen's ML Interviews book
- A [Deep Learning Interviews](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.00650) book  that contains many questions testing your ML and DL knowledge.

If you are looking to solve more theory questions, you can work through the exercises of Bishop's [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) book, although I am not sure if the solutions are available online.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find a high quality and well recognized course, you can pay extra for a Certificate:

   - https://ocw.mit.edu/search/?t=Artificial+Intelligence
   - https://www.edx.org/course/the-analytics-edge
2. Try answering some of these questions, network with others:

   - [https://mathoverflow.net/](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=views%3A5000..+answers%3A0+closed%3A0)
3. Write a few papers, publish, and try to obtain an [endorsement](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement).